# get a reference to a containing class in java

Tags: java

I am new to Java. I'm a C++ programmer, reading some Java code. I have this class definition:

```
class Container {
    long ID;

    class Contained {
        void foo(){
            long parentID = ID;
        }
    }
}
```

I see that Contained can access any member of the Container class, simply by name.

I have one question:

What is going on here? In C++ these classes would be unrelated. But in Java, it seems, the contained class object seems to be implicitly tied to the instance of the parent class object.

Thanks
Manish

PS: Sorry, I know I could pick up a book on Java, but I was hoping someone could help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `Contained` class is not declared as `static`, it means that it can only exist within an instance of a `Container` class and hence has access to all of the methods and variables of `Container`.

If you had declared `Contained` as `static`, it would imitate the C++ usage that you're more used to -- that is, you could have an instance of the nested class without having an instance of `Container`.

See [Java inner class and static nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class/70358#70358) for further details.

Answer (score 3):

In Java these are called nested classes. There are several types of nested classes with different semantics. There is info at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html.

In your example that is an inner class, so its instances exist *within an instance* of the outer class.

Answer (score 0):

This is a nested class. Its lifecycle is tied to the parent class. Read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) for full understanding.